# Is there any fucntion that can report the results of many multiple linear regression models

Tags: r

I'm fitting many models like this example:

```
model<-lm(vl~sex+race+gene1+gene2)
anova(model)
model<-lm(vl~sex+race+gene3+gene4)
anova(model)
model<-lm(vl~sex+race+gene5+gene6)
anova(model)
model<-lm(vl~sex+race+gene7+gene8)
anova(model)
model<-lm(vl~sex+race+gene9+gene10)
anova(model)
```

I want a function or R package that can extract all the p values from those models and put them in one table. I have so many models that I cannot copy and past every p value. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with the mtcars dataset:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

table <- mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl = as_factor(cyl)) %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    group_split() %>% 
    map_dfr(.f = function(df) {
    lm(mpg ~ am+disp+gear, data = df) %>% 
            glance() %>% 
            add_column(cyl = unique(df$cyl), .before = 1)
})

table
```

Output:

```
 cyl   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <fct>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 4         0.866         0.808  1.98     15.0  0.00196     3 -20.6   51.2  53.2    27.3            7    11
2 6         0.609         0.218  1.29      1.56 0.362       3  -8.72  27.4  27.2     4.96           3     7
3 8         0.272         0.139  2.38      2.05 0.175       2 -30.3   68.6  71.1    62.1           11    14
```